# S3 upload: are waiters needed?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using PHP to upload a file to `S3` using `PutObject`.

The file needs to be accessible right after uploading. Do I need to use [`Waiters`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-waiters.html) to ensure that?

Under what circumstances would the file not be available right after the `PutObject` completes? I did some simple testing by calling `HeadObject` right after `PutObject` and it seems that there is no need for `Waiters`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 uses read-after-write consistency so you shouldn't need a `Waiter` if the PUT has completed. For more information [check out the FAQ for S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/).